# wxCopyFile; "ERROR 5: Access is denied" even when running with administrator privilages

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm writing a very simple program which edits an XML file and copies a user specified image to the folder in which the .exe runs.

The problem I'm having is with wxCopyFile. When I first ran the program (with debug mode in Visual Studio 2019) I got "error 5: Access denied", so I tried running the .exe from the Debug folder. Again, I got the same error. Then I ran it as administrator and again I got the same error! After that, I copied the .exe at another folder, tried it with administrator privileges and once again, it didn't work!

Here is the code where the program asks the user to select his desired image:

```
void GUI::OnSelectImg(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxFileDialog* selectImage = new wxFileDialog(NULL,
        wxString("Select the country's flag..."),
        wxEmptyString,
        wxEmptyString,
        wxT("PNG image files (*.png)|*.png") //Allow only pngs!
    );

    if (selectImage->ShowModal() == wxID_CANCEL) {
        delete selectImage;
        return;
    }

    fileMGR.SetImagePath(selectImage->GetPath());
    imagePathLabel->SetLabel(selectImage->GetPath()); //Updates the label
    delete selectImage;
}
```

And the part with wxCopyFile

```
void GUI::OnAddCountry(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    //Has he specified a flag?
    if (fileMGR.GetImagePath().IsEmpty()) {
        wxMessageBox(
            wxString("You have not specified an image for the country's flag!\nSpecify one and try again!"),
            "No image selected!",
            wxOK | wxICON_ERROR,
            this
        );
        return;
    }

    if (!wxCopyFile(fileMGR.GetImagePath(), wxStandardPaths::Get().GetDataDir())) {
        wxMessageBox(
            wxString("Failed to copy the selected image!"),
            "Failed to copy the image!",
            wxOK | wxICON_ERROR,
            this
        );
        return;
    }

    //Other not important actions...
}
```

And here is also [the error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0exY.png). What I'm I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Test - can you copy the file manually, either from the command prompt or drag-drop?

Comment: Yes I can, both by drag-and-drop and with CMD (without even giving it administrator privileges)

Comment: Then the destination file is probably in-use (open) when your program is running.

Comment: @RichardCritten Neither the destination nor the source file is open.

Comment: It might be locked by your .exe while running as alluded to by @RichardCritten... Once you open and load the file into your program, check if it is indeed locked (before copying)

Comment: @segmentation_fault Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I checked if the file is locked by the .exe, but it isn't. I ended up using fopen() to open the image as a binary file and copy it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wxCopyFile() documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.5/group__group__funcmacro__file.html#ga65ec867ed441231ed2ba67b3bb5ee4e3) it appears that both its arguments must be file names; however, your second argument is a directory. This results in the function trying to create a file where a directory with the same name already exists, resulting into the error.

Therefore, you need to provide a full path including the file name instead of just the directory name for the second argument too. wxCopyFile() seems to mimic [CopyFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) which it uses on MSW. It can be argued that their behaviour is not the most convenient one but that would be beyond the point of this question.